VS2022 Community edition hangs periodically on running Azure Function app in debug mode
I have an existing Azure function app, using .Net 8 in isolated process mode.  I have worked with it for months in VS2022 Enterprise.  On a new laptop, I have VS2022 Community edition.  When launching the application in debug mode, it will frequently hang during the startup.  Verbose mode is on and the last line displayed before hanging is "Reading functions metadata (Worker)".
I have found that cleaning the solution has no affect.  Deleting the bin folder and rebuilding may allow it to start normally.  Deleting the bin folder AND restarting VS2022 almost always allows it to launch properly.  Stopping the debugging session and restarting causes the cycle to begin again.
The problem never occurred in VS2022 Enterprise on a different machine.  Running the same solution in JetBrains Rider has no issues.
Any ideas on what the cause is and workaround?


Your problem may be due to a different VS settings. Try this methods to determine if the issue is related that or not.
Navigate to Tool > Options > Search “Settings” and select Import and Export Settings to locate the path of your Visual Studio configuration file. You can then copy your Visual Studio Enterprise configuration and import it into Visual Studio Community.

Thanks for the suggestions but none of these has had an effect. Still struggling with this.

Your Visual Studio 2022 community edition is trying to read the function metadata to find the Function triggers inside your project.
Try to uninstall the Azure Functions core tools from :-
C\Users\AppData\Local\azure-functions-core-tools and C\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools Then install the latest version of Azure Functions Core tools again from this link.
Also, Check if your host.json file is correct and present in your Function app project:-
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}

My .net 8.0 Isolated Function code for HttpTrigger:-
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp12
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}

Output:-

My function app csproj:-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Also, Retry the Azure Developer extension workload installation in your Visual Studio Installer that includes Azure Functions support.
As an alternative you can also start triggering your Function by the command below:-
func host start --verbose

Refer this SO thread for more insights.
